# Why imap_open gives the error “SSL negotiation failed” when connecting without SSL

Tags: php, imap, imap-open

I am trying to connect to imap server using imap_open() php function wihtout SSL, but I got error
"SSL negotiation failed"
What could be the reason?

I run

```
imap_open("{myhost.com:143/imap}INBOX", "mylogin", "mypassword", 0, 0, ['DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => ['GSSAPI', 'NTLM']]);
$err = imap_last_error();
```

As a result connection is failed and error is
"TLS/SSL failure for myhost.com: SSL negotiation failed"

Comment: It may be trying STARTTLS.  Use /notls to turn off this feature.

Comment: I'd try `imap_open("{myhost.com:143/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX",` first and `/notls` only if that fails.